# Форматирование массива из бд

Tags: php, json

имеется массив данных 1 поля из Базы Данных и имеет вид

```
[{"summary_elapsed":"12"},{"summary_elapsed":"11"},{"summary_elapsed":"234"},{"summary_elapsed":"123"}]
```

Мне нужно отформатировать строку и получить данные в таком виде:

```
 ["11","12","234","123"]
```

После вывода данных из бд они идут через json_encode() в js скрипт.
Помогите регулярное выражение написать пожалуйста, или есть другой способ?

Comment: Ты слишком хорош чтобы гуглить `json php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

json это формат передачи данных, совместимый с объектной нотацией Javascript. для работы с ним в различных языках программирования существует набор различных функций. А вот регулярные выражения, это инструмент обработки текста и поиска в нем "шаблонов". Конечно, поскольку json эт структурированный объект, то вы можете составить регулярные выражение для извлечения данных, но это в корне не верный путь, и использовать следует именно существующие функции.

в вашем случае после извлечения данных из БД следует их декодировать, получить значения по имени поля и закодировать их обратно в массив.

```
  $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
  $values = array_column($data, 'summary_elapsed');
  $json_values = json_encode($values);
```

Если ваша СУБД позволяет обрабатывать JSON данные, то извлечь непосредственные значения можно напрямки в SQL-запросе.

Comment: да при чем здесь "JSON данные". не лежит этот массив в базе. клиент просто напустил json_encode на полученный из бд массив строк

Comment: @Ипатьев может и так. я прочитал "1 поля из БД" как что приведенный json хранится в поле БД. Если это выборка по одному полю закодированная, то суть дела не меняется, array_column+json_encode в любом случае решает, кхм, проблему, пока он и правда не начал его гонять через регулярки